# how can i run a specific angular spec test file in NX workspace?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, karma-jasmine, ngrx, nrwl

is there any way to run an specific angular spec test file in Nx work space?

Recently i moved my  Angular 4 cli application into Nx work space.   Previously i used **fdescribe** to achieve this functionality.
So please suggest me if there is any option to do this in Nx work space?

Comment: There's a few similar/duplicate answers so I'll just comment here a couple of things that caught me out here:  1. You don't need to specify the full/relative path to the file; you can just use the filename.  2. If you do specify a path, it doesn't work with backslash (Windows-style), you must use forward slash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be the same way we do it for a single app, but please note you should use --app='your-app-name' along with ng test, so the final command looks like below,

```
ng test --app='app1'
```

Comment: how to test it for a lib?

Comment: Libs cannot be tested individually, we can add fdescribe to the spec file in lib and run test on the app that uses the lib.

Comment: Got the solution. I had to add an `app`. Angular cli expects main.ts. through the app consuming the lib, we can execute the tests for the lib

Answer (score 64):

This worked for me

```
 nx test --test-file example.spec.ts
```

Comment: You can even be more specific and add `--test-name-pattern=regex` to target a specific test in that file.

Comment: You need to specify project name, (the workspace might have multiple projects). So like this: `nx test projectName --test-file example.spec.ts`

Comment: Thank you. I needed this as well, so sharing: `--codeCoverage` flag.

Answer (score 40):

This worked for me:

```
nx run <project-name>:test --testFile=<file-name>
```

Answer (score 6):

For me the **watch** tag did the magic:

`ng test --watch`

Before running through everything it offered me the following options:

```
 › Press a to run all tests.
 › Press f to run only failed tests.
 › Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 › Press t to filter by a test name regex pattern.
 › Press q to quit watch mode.
 › Press Enter to trigger a test run.
```

Selecting the **'p' option** and typing `xy.service.spec.ts` worked fine.

Note: I'm using not the latest version (`"@nrwl/nx": "7.4.0"`)

Answer (score 4):

this worked for me:

```
nx run <project-name>:test --testFile <filename.spec.ts>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't see how this is any different from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69910939/2540278 (itself marginally different from the top voted answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's actually
`nx run <project-name>:test --testFile=<pathtofile.spec.ts>`

Use Unix style for path (/ instead of ).

You can run with `--watch` option if you want the process to keep running tests  every time you make a code change.